# Enter data in textarea using mechanize Python

Tags: python, forms, beautifulsoup, mechanize, python-requests

I'm trying to enter data into a text area where it says

```
<textarea class="help_text" cols="40" id="annotation_text" name="annotation[text]" rows="15" style="box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray; padding: 5px; width: 600px;" title="Enter or paste text to be annotated"></textarea>
```

but I'm confused how to do it since there is no form associated with it. Here's the [link](http://bioportal.bioontology.org/annotator) to the website. I really appreciate any help on how to enter the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be different solutions applied here, though it is pretty clear - this is not an easy case for `mechanize`. Better make that submission (POST request) using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/):

```
import requests

url = 'http://bioportal.bioontology.org/annotator'
params = {
    'text': 'Sample text',  # this is the contents of the text area
    'longest_only': 'false',
    'raw': 'true'
}

# start a web-scraping session (mostly, for maintaining cookies)
session = requests.Session()
session.get(url)

# submit the "form"
response = session.post(url, data=params)
data = response.json()

# get the annotations
for annotation in data['annotations']:
    print annotation['annotatedClass']['prefLabel']
```

Prints:

```
Sample
sample
sample
sample
Specimen
Sample
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That's perfect. Could you tell me how I can get the context column as well.

Comment: @amy just explore what the `annotation` variable in the loop contains. Print it out and see what columns are there, then get the `context` in a similar manner as in the answer I'm getting the class. Let me know if you'll have difficulties. Thanks.

Comment: Sure. My bad! I was excited seeing a working solution, which is the result of a very dumb question. Thank you very much for your answer.